# Step by step instructions on building Sphinx 4

Tags: java, ant, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to run a demo for Sphinx 4 using the steps given here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/
However, I don't understand what it's trying to tell me
I have java, jre, eclipse-juno and everything needed to compile java as well as android programs
But the tutorial I linked says I should run ant
What is ant and how do I run it?
In one of the steps it tells to set environment variables related to java and ant, and it says to do so using

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_14
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.0
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.0/bin:$PATH
```

I thought it was supposed to be done in the `Environment Variables` in My Computer properties. What is this export command?

Is there an easy to understand step by step guide that shows how to run a demo program for Sphinx 4?

Answer (score 1):

Full algorithm of running sphinx 4 demos in eclipse:

1. Download and unpack sphinx4-1.0beta6 from http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download/
2. Run eclipse. Create new workspace if needed.
3. In eclipse: File => Import Project = > Existing Project from File System => choose the folder with sphinx4.
4. Run shinx4/lib/jsapi.exe
5. Build sphin4 and demos with ant: chose (right click) build.xml in eclipse project explorer => Run As =>  Ant Build. Repeat with demo.xml.
6. Complete! You can run the demos from eclipse. For example: right click on edu.cmu.shinx.demo.hellongram => Run As => Java Application. You can see output in eclipse console.

Answer (score -1):

Well, i just made a java program working for helloworld. And i am a 15 year old newbie. so i think that what i have done, you can do for sure. I had a look at the tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0f3vvCJWyo you should not have any problems with it. If you do just comment, and yah put a tick besides my answer if i helped you. :D

Note: You have to use the latest beta bin version.
First, Try to make it just as he makes it in the video and then maybe you know what you really needed